# When using the flutter_local_notifications plugin, pending notifications are cancelled after a reboot

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple TODO app in *flutter* with reminder functionality. I am using the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin's `scheduled notification` option and it words as expected.

However, whenever I reboot the device all scheduled notifications are cancelled automatically.

Is there any way to prevent scheduled notifications from being cancelled during a reboot?

Edit: solved by using [flutter_background_fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notifications are not persistent and will always be gone after the system restart or reboot. If you want them to reappear you need to do that yourself,  listening to [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and then acting appropriately which means posting your notifications again.

Comment: thank you, sir, done by using https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch